# ReactJS rendering issue with edited array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Why does ReactJS remove the last element when the array is different after removing the middle element when using array.splice?

This is my code. I am using React-Redux.

```
const reducerNotesAndLogin = (state = initialState, action) => {
var tableNotes = "notities";
var tableCategories = "categories";

switch(action.type){
case "CATEGORY_REMOVE":
        // Remove the category
        var newCategories = state.categories;

        console.log("state.categories", state.categories);
        console.log("before: ", {newCategories});
        var index = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < newCategories.length; i++){
            if(newCategories[i].id === action.payload.categoryId){

                newCategories.splice(i, 1);
                index = i;
                i--;
            }
        }

        console.log("after: ", {newCategories});

        state = {
            ...state,
            categories: newCategories
        }

break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return state;
}

export default reducerNotesAndLogin;
```

Output below (I deleted the middle element. My web app always removes the last element of the categories (but not from the array).

**Step 1: Initial state**

[image: Initial state of app]

**Step 2: Remove middle item, expecting the middle item to be removed.**

[image: Problem]

**Step 3: Confusion**

Why is the array correct, but the view incorrect? I am updating the state.categories correctly right?

This is my render code (as is - without filtering away any other code that mihgt be important)

CategoriesBody:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import CategoryItem from './CategoryItem';

import Button from './../../Button';
import store from '../../../redux/store-index';

class CategoriesBody extends React.Component {
render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <ul className="list--notes">
                {this.props.categories.map((category) => {
                    if(category.id === undefined){ // No categories
                        return <li>No categories</li>
                        } else {
                            return (
                                <div>
                                    <CategoryItem category={category} />
                                    <div className="mb-small hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"> </div>
                                </div>
                            );
                        }
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        categories: state.reducerNotesAndLogin.categories,
        categoriesLength: state.reducerNotesAndLogin.categories.length
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CategoriesBody);
```

CategoriesItem.js:

```
    import React from 'react';
import store from './../../../redux/store-index';
import Button from './../../Button';

class CategoryItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super();
        this.state = {
            edit: false,
            categoryName: props.category.categoryName,
            categoryColor: props.category.categoryColor
        }

        this.onClickEdit = this.onClickEdit.bind(this);

        this.onChangeCategoryColor = this.onChangeCategoryColor.bind(this);
        this.onChangeInputCategoryName = this.onChangeInputCategoryName.bind(this);

        this.onClickEditSave = this.onClickEditSave.bind(this);
        this.onClickEditCancel = this.onClickEditCancel.bind(this);
    }

    removeCategory(id, name){
        console.log("nsvbsvbfjvbdjhbvv");
        store.dispatch({ type: "CATEGORY_REMOVE", payload: {
            categoryId: id
        }});

        // store.dispatch({type: "NOTIFY", payload: {
        //     type: 'success',
        //     message: 'Category "' + name + '" removed!'
        // }});
    }

    onClickEdit(){
        this.setState({
            edit: true
        });
    }

    onChangeCategoryColor(e){
        this.setState({
            categoryColor: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeInputCategoryName(e){
        this.setState({
            categoryName: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onClickEditSave(){
        this.setState({
            edit: false,
            categoryName: this.state.categoryName,
            categoryColor: this.state.categoryColor
        });

        store.dispatch({type: "CATEGORY_EDIT", payload: {
            categoryId: this.props.category.id,
            categoryName: this.state.categoryName,
            categoryColor: this.state.categoryColor
        }});

        store.dispatch({type: "NOTIFY", payload: {
            type: "success",
            message: "Category saved!"
        }});
    }

    onClickEditCancel(){
        this.setState({
            edit: false,
            categoryName: this.props.category.categoryName,
            categoryColor: this.props.category.categoryColor
        });
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <li key={this.props.category.id} className={this.state.edit === true ? "mt mb" : "flex-justify-between flex-align-center"}>
                <div className={this.state.edit === true ? "d-none" : ""}>
                    <div className="input--color" style={{
                        backgroundColor: this.state.categoryColor
                        }}>&nbsp;</div>

                    {this.state.categoryName}

                </div>

                {/* Mobile */}
                <div className={this.state.edit === true ? "d-none" : "hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"}>
                    <Button onClick={() => this.onClickEdit()} buttonType="primary">Edit</Button>
                    <div className="mt-small"> </div>
                    <Button onClick={() => this.removeCategory(this.props.category.id, this.props.category.categoryName)} type="primary">Remove</Button>
                </div>

                {/* Tablet and desktop */}
                <div className={this.state.edit === true ? "d-none" : "hidden-xs"}>
                    <div style={{float:'left',}}><Button onClick={() => this.onClickEdit()} buttonType="primary">Edit</Button></div>
                    <div style={{float:'left',marginLeft:'15px'}}><Button onClick={() => this.removeCategory(this.props.category.id, this.props.category.categoryName)} type="primary">Remove</Button></div>
                </div>


                {/* EDITING STATE */}

                <div className={this.state.edit === true ? "" : "d-none"}>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-xs-12">
                            <input onChange={this.onChangeCategoryColor} className="input--wide" type="color" value={this.state.categoryColor} 
                                style={{backgroundColor: this.state.categoryColor, height: '30px'}}
                            />
                            <input onChange={this.onChangeInputCategoryName} className="input--wide" type="text" value={this.state.categoryName} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row mt">
                        <div className="col-xs-12">
                            <Button buttonType="primary" onClick={() => this.onClickEditSave()}>Save</Button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row mt-small">
                        <div className="col-xs-12">
                            <Button buttonType="secondary" onClick={() => this.onClickEditCancel()}>Cancel</Button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        )
    }
}

export default CategoryItem;
```

I think it has something to do with the rendering. Because the arrays are correct when I console.log them. Only the view is different...

Comment: Can you share the rendering code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer after looking through it with a friend of mine. The solution is pretty simple...

Lesson 101: Make sure that you have a unique "key" property when looping through an array in your UI.

The solution is to add this to my code:

```
<div key={category.id}>
    {this.props.categories.map....
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not modify the state in reducer directly. Create a copy of state value and then modify it.

Change:

```
var newCategories = state.categories;
```

To:

```
var newCategories = [...state.categories];
```

You should not modify the same array while looping through it.

```
for (var i = 0; i < newCategories.length; i++) {
      if (newCategories[i].id === action.payload.categoryId) {
        newCategories.splice(i, 1);
        index = i;
        i--;
      }
    }
```

Comment: What does newCategories = [...state.categories] do? It makes a copy of the array?

Comment: yes, it makes a shallow copy of the array. https://we-are.bookmyshow.com/understanding-deep-and-shallow-copy-in-javascript-13438bad941c